# Running SpringMVC App in intelliJ, now what?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I'm done with my development, so when I deploy on tomcat go to localhost:8080, it goes to my home page...and everythign works. Now I want this to be live, how / what do i put and where?

expected unhelpful answer: "put it on your server" 
better answer : go to the public_html folder of your server and put in the .war file (although this didn't work, it was a specific answer and helpful)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your continuous integration server would do this for you. But if you're not using that, you can deploy from your dev machine. Use the [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html).

You need to setup your remote tomcat server to enable remote deploy. In `conf/tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <user 
    name="manager" 
    password="s3cr3t" 
    roles="manager-script" 
  />
</tomcat-users>
```

In your maven `pom.xml` build/plugins section:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <url>http://my-remote-server.com/manager/text</url>
    <update>true</update>
    <username>manager</username>
    <password>s3cr3t</password>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then run `mvn clean package tomcat7:deploy`

Comment: any suggestions on a free domain that will support tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Get a server, install tomcat, install possibly a http server (apache, nginx, etc.), configure them, get a domain name, configure everything properly, deploy your .war to tomcat (if you did this on your computer, you should be able to do it on any server) and there you go.